# Why do my location values not make sense

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I have a 12m block and a second 2m block.

I aligned the bottoms in space so they both had the same z value.

I typed in `10` for the Z value for block 2, which should bring it ~5/6 of the way up block 1. Instead, it hovers above it.

[image]

[image]

How can making the z-axis location 10m make it hover above a 12m block?

Comment: Looks like your objects origins aren't where you expect them to be.

Comment: @L0Lock Im not sure what that means or how to change it. Im very new to Blender/Fusion360. Just got a 3D printer and trying to learn as I go.

What does the origin of the object have to do with an object located at 10m hovering above a 12m thick object?  Not being snarky, just dont know how to ask that any other way. Really confused on this one

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that you don't understand how objects work. [Objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/introduction.html) are virtual containers that can contain certain data-blocks, such as meshes, curves, lights, ...

To be able to exist in the 3D World, objects have an origin:

> Each object has an origin point. The location of this point determines where the object is located in 3D space. When an object is selected, a small circle appears, denoting the origin point. The location of the origin point is important when translating, rotating or scaling an object.
>
> Source: [**Object Origin — Blender Manual**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/origin.html)

If we take example from the default cube:

[image]

The origin of that cube is that dot in the middle. All objects you create by default in Blender from the Add menu have their origin somewhat at their center. But this can be changed as you wish, for example:

[image]

All these are different cubes. Even though they look the same, their origins aren't. If I set them all to be located at the world center, they look like this:

[image]

When you say:

> I typed in "10" for the z value for block 2, which should bring it ~5/6 of the way up block 1. Instead, it hovers above it.

Blender operates these coordinates from the origin points of the respective objects. And it seems they are not what you expect, since it doesn't give the result you thought it would. Perhaps the 2m thick block have its origin a few units below it. Or your 12m thick block is a bit "sinked" from its origin. Or a little bit of both.

---

Assuming what you want is something that looks like this:

[image]

And that you want to set the Z location to be counted from the visual bottom of your meshes. That means that you need your objects' origins to be at the bottom of their meshes. So let's do that:

### Changing the objects origins

There are two quick ways to do this:

- Using the 3D Cursor:

  - Select an object
  - <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into Edit mode
  - Select the bottom face
  - <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to Selected
  - <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into Object mode
  - <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> the object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor
  - Repeat for other object.
- Transforming the origin directly:

  - In Object mode, in the top right corner of the viewport, open the Options popover and enable Affect Only Origins:
    [image]
  - In the top middle of the viewport, set the Snapping to target Vertex:
    [image]
  - Select one object. Press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to start moving on the Z axis, hold down <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> to snap and <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> the object's lowest vertex.
  - Repeat for other object
  - Disable Affect Only Origin.

### Wrap up

Now you should be able to write the location values you want.

If your objects dimensions are definitive, it would be smart to also select your objects and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Scale. That way, their current dimensions become their new "default" scale: their scale value become 1:1:1 while preserving their dimensions. It will make modifiers and constraint work correctly (as they work from the object's scale) and it will be easier for you to work with different scale too.

Comment: This was a phenomenal explanation and I totally see my misunderstanding now. Thank you, @L0Lock. My only follow up here is WHEN should I be applying Scale? Should I be doing it once the dimensionality is where I want it? If I resize at some point to account for something unseen, should I re-apply scale again, or should it only be done once?

Comment: Glad I could help! Applying scale can be done at any time. There isn't really a set-in-stone rule for it, it depends on what you need to do, and there are so many cases where it matters or not that everybody just learns on the spot. But basically, if you ever encounter a tool giving weird results - especially that makes your mesh move disproportionately -  (i.e. squished UVs, armature deforming wrong), unapplied scales are a common culprit.